# Google Dynamic Remarketing tag not recognized

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

Trying to setup dynamic remarketing. Analytics and Adwords are linked and in use for some time now.

I modified the Analytics tag to require displayfeatures and set customer dimensions. I also added an extra event and pageview tag for testing purposes.

However, in adwords I get the message "**We haven't detected the Google Analytics remarketing functionality on your website.**"

Below are the tags currently active on the site:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'XX-00000000-0', 'auto');
  ga('require', 'displayfeatures');

  ga('set', 'dimension1', 'FOOBAR1, FOOBAR2, FOOBAR3');
  ga('set', 'dimension2', 'home');
  ga('set', 'dimension3', '44.44, 55.55, 66.66');

  ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
ga('send', 'event', 'product', 'view', {
  'dimension1': 'FOOBAR4, FOOBAR5, FOOBAR6',
  'dimension2': 'product',
  'dimension3': '77.77, 88.88, 99.99'
});
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
ga('send', 'pageview', {
  'dimension1':'FOOBAR7, FOOBAR8, FOOBAR9',
  'dimension2':'cart',
  'dimension3':'11.11, 22.22, 33.33',
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and brought on our Adwords rep to help mediate between GA. They claimed it may have something to do with the CMS, but nonetheless asked to try it out with Google Tag Manager.

Tried Google Tag Manager and the problem went away.